# How to emulate iOS, Windows Phone and Blackberries on Ubuntu

Tags: android, ios, gwt, blackberry, cordova

I'm planning on using GWT and PhoneGap to produce native apps for Android, iOS, Windows Phone and Blackberry.

I'm *vaguely* familiar with pure Android development (I've downloaded the SDK, etc.) and understand that the SDK comes with its own Dalvik Emulator.

But after a cursory inspection of the iOS and Blackberry SDKs, it doesn't look like they have any emulators that will port over to an Ubuntu desktop.

What I want is a situation where I develop these native apps via GWT and PhoneGap on my Ubuntu laptop, and when PhoneGap wraps each end-deliverable and produces the correct binary (APK, IPA, etc.) I can just throw it into the correct emulator and see it in action.

As far as I know this is not possible, so do I have any options here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The iOS _simulator_ is OSX only.  You may be able to deploy your binary OTA to your device though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPhone development requires a computer running Mac OS X. However, It does seem that you can develop for iPhone under Linux using [monotouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch/). But, It's not in the native code of iPhone (Objective C) so the performance is no guarantee.

Wine still can't run so many applications anyway, so I doubt it could run Visual Studio. [Here's](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20359) a link that claims that it can't, unless you do some hacking steps. However, There is an alternative for Visual studio for creating C# applications (Mono) so it may be possible.

BlackBerry should support Java and C++, so it's probably possible to develop for it on Ubuntu.

Comment: it doesn't? i thought it can . so it supports only winforms and console , and maybe server side and WCF? anyway , updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @android developer (+1) - My wife has an iPhone - is there a way to set up a "QA"/testing account with the Apple App Store and deploy to just her phone but without making the app publicly-accessible to anyone else? That solution would be hack-a-licious but would get the basic job done (I'm not gonna go shell out $3K for an apple just so I can get access to the iOS simulator!).

Comment: well , you could install the macOS on your computer (for example inside "virturl box") and then code in apple's xCode IDE . that would take less money . however , since i've never done it , i think you might have problems with installation of the app . maybe if the iphone was jailbroken you could put the ipk file (the installation file for iOS) of the app into the iphone and install it . i don't think you have to have an account in order to develop apps .you have to have it in order to publish it on the app-store of apple.

Comment: Are you sure OSX runs on Virtual Box. A buddy of mine told me you can run Apple VMs on anything that's not Apple hardware. True?

Comment: Edit to the above: "A buddy of mine told me you **cannot** run Apple software (including VMs) on anything that's not Apple hardware. True?"

Comment: never tried it for macOS , but here's a list of their supported OSs : https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes .